# Keystone.js self signed certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, keystonejs

I'm trying to run Keystone.js with a self signed SSL certificate. Not working well...

```
Fri, 22 Jul 2016 06:36:57 GMT uncaughtException: self signed certificate
Error: self signed certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1057:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:596:8)
```

Mongoose accepts a parameter sslValidate=false. Anyway to pass that to Keystone?

Comment: Note that Keystone now has letsencrypt.org support, so you can use that same key for your mongo db. https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/v0.3.x/HISTORY.md#v0322--2016-07-22

Answer (score 2):

In v0.4, you can pass options to Mongoose via the `mongo options` setting.

So e.g.

```
keystone.init({
  'mongo options': {sslValidate: false}
})
```

In v0.3 you will need to configure Mongoose yourself and pass it via the `mongoose` setting.

Comment: Not seeing that option in the documentation. Are you sure this is supported?

http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration

Comment: Oops you are  right, that is for Keystone v0.4. Not possible in v0.3, you will need to set up Mongoose yourself :( The new code is here: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/721e5568c2176a8c160813ae3c192f69ae17b6f2/lib/core/openDatabaseConnection.js#L15